# Apache POI - Apply filter based upon column value

Tags: apache-poi

I have a Excel sheet, with some columns(Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4). I want to read only rows with Column4="A" value using Apache POI. Please share any working  example. The relevant information is not available within Apache POI website with example. Also, I want to copy the filtered set to another excel sheet. please share sample code.

Comment: _Please share any working example_ It works a bit different. First you have to post a _non-working_ example of what you have tried, explain where you have difficulties  and then, probably, it would be turned into a working example.

Comment: Iterating rows in sheets: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/IterateCells.java

Use this API to remove the rows you don't need: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#removeRow-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row-

Use this API to save the modified workbook: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#write-java.io.OutputStream-